# How do you populate the time zone table for Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Google Cloud SQL does not come with the timezone table pre-loaded. How do you populate this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First setup your Cloud SQL instance so you can access it remotely.

I then ran the following command on a Ubuntu 14.04 machine that had MySQL on it. Replace IP_ADDRESS with your Cloud SQL instance remote IP.

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p -h IP_ADDRESS mysql
```

You can probably run this on other systems other than Ubuntu, but Ubuntu 14.04 had a similar version as Cloud SQL so just check your MySQL version before running it.